# Reading MSSQL .bak files in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I have recently inherited the sad task of recovering data from an old MSSQL .bak file. As this is going into a web database, it would be both interesting and ideal if it could be accessed and read by PHP.

I do not currently have access to a Windows machine from which to load the SQL Management console from MS which allows me to restore this backup file.

Does anyone know if there are any libraries out there which will facilitate the access of the data in this .bak file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is such a tool, the [Red-Gate Virtual Restore](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-virtual-restore/). It does require, however, a full SQL Server installation, as the tool is only a virtual file mapper that allows the SQL Server instance to read the .bak file w/o  a proper restore by mapping the IO requests from the SQL Server into the .bak file (see [Hyperbak](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-virtual-restore/hyperbac-powered)). The benefit of the tool is to allow inspection of .bak file content and retrieval of data w/o a full restore (primarily w/o creating the actual .MDF/.LDF files needed for restoring the database).

In your case you should restore the .bak file in a SQL Server instance of appropriate version. If you're lucky and the original database does not contain Enterprise only features ([`sys.dm_db_persisted_sku_features`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280724.aspx) was empty) and the database does not exceed the 10Gb SQL Express limit, then you will be able to restore the backup file with a free [SQL Server 2008R2 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23650) instance.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the only feasible way to read the data out of those binary .bak files, is via the MS SQL Management Console. As you probably noticed it's not plain text which could be parsed easily with any other tools, and as far as I (and Google) are aware, there are no reliable tools which can process those bak files other than the actual MS tool provided to accomplish said task. You're going to have to install the correct version of SQL to read that file.

Comment: Indeed, I have consulted the Google overlords before posting here, and was singularly unsuccessful.

Comment: Yup -- it's always nice to be able to give suggestions that can't be found on Google, but this is not one of those cases!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have MS SQL but you have some version of Windows you can try with the Microsoft SQL Server 2000 Desktop Engine. Free download available at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22661

I found this live at http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?65,72796,207081#msg-207081
where Tim mentions that it's possible to create a live ODBC datasource.

So far I haven't been successful with this myself though (it's not installing on my virtual machine with XP) and I'll probably get a proper SQL dump one of these days.